# Is it conceivable to return a status code 204 on a request with POST?

Tags: http, http-post, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-204

Is it conceivable (under certain circumstances) to return a status code 204 (no content) on a request with POST?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's actually what a successful call is supposed to return when the response body is empty. But it hasn't caught on as a convention for POST, and `content-length: 0` is good enough.